# Handle undeclared dict key in Python

Tags: python, exception

In my Ruby application I have a hash table:

```rb
c = {:sample => 1,:another => 2}
```

I can handle the table like this:

```rb
[c[:sample].nil? , c[:another].nil? ,c[:not_in_list].nil?]
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Python. I created a new dictionary:

```
c = {"sample":1, "another":2}
```

I couldn't handle the nil value exception for:

```
c["not-in-dictionary"]
```

I tried this:

```
c[:not_in_dictionery] is not None
```

and it is returning an exception instead of `False.` How do I handle this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your particular case, you should probably do this instead of comparing with `None`:

```
"not_in_dictionary" in c
```

If you were literally using this code, it will not work:

```
c[:not_in_dictionary] is not None
```

Python doesn't have special `:`keywords for dictionary keys; ordinary strings are used instead.

---

The ordinary behaviour in Python is to raise an exception when you request a missing key, and let you handle the exception.

```python
d = {"a": 2, "c": 3}

try:
    print d["b"]
except KeyError:
    print "There is no b in our dict!"
```

If you want to get `None` if a value is missing you can use the `dict`'s `.get` method to return a value (`None` by default) if the key is missing.

```python
print d.get("a") # prints 2
print d.get("b") # prints None
print d.get("b", 0) # prints 0
```

To just check if a key has a value in a `dict`, use the `in` or `not in` keywords.

```python
print "a" in d # True
print "b" in d # False
print "c" not in d # False
print "d" not in d # True
```

---

Python includes a module that allows you to define dictionaries that return a default value instead of an error when used normally: [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects). You could use it like this:

```python
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)
print "b" in d # False
print d["b"] # None
print d["b"] == None # True
print "b" in d # True
```

Notice the confusing behaviour with `in`. When you look up a key for the first time, it adds it pointing to the default value, so it's now considered to be `in` the `dict`.

Comment: Minor nit:  `d.get("a", None)` is, umh, over-specified.  It's equivalent to `d.get("a")`.  You only need the second argument for a default value (other than `None`, which is the default default, so to speak).

Comment: Maybe defaultdict is worth mentioning too.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks Thanks. I need one more answer.I want to return True if the variable are exists?. any way?

Comment: @shajin That's just `"variable" in d`! :)

Comment: @Jeremy Banks how we can write opposite of __contains__ for dist?  like "if 'False' not contains in dist" .I tried if !dist.__contains__("False"). error generated :)

Comment: `!` is `not` in Python, so you can write `if not "name" in d:` or `if "name" not in d:`.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks Thanks.I raise this as another question.Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756132/how-to-find-whether-a-value-is-not-contains-in-a-list-or-dist-in-python Thanks

Comment: @shajin If you're finished with this question, could you accept it if it was what you needed? :)