# How to find whether a value is not contains in a List or Dist in Python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I can use  `dist.__ contains__ (value)` to know whether a value is included or not in a List or Dist.But I need to return True if a value is not included in dist or list.
I tried  `If !dist._contains _(value)` .Obviously, not worked.Please give me a solution.

Comment: I am using unless keyword in Ruby.Can I use that in Python?

Comment: Do you mean `dict`?  If so, please fix your question to spell `dict` correctly.  Thousands of people could see  (and learn from) this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:13:53) 
>>> 3 in [1, 2, 3] # To know if a value is in a list
True
>>> 3 in {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'} # To know if a value is in keys of a dict
True
>>> 'three' in {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}.values() # To know if a value is in values of a dict
True
>>>
```

Use `not in` instead of `in` if you want to verify if a value is *not* in a list/dict.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple:

```
if value not in dist:
```

Comment: Started learning python on yesterday night. thats why. :) nyway thanks

Comment: @shajin: Accept the answer you're going to use going forward.  "Thanks" are nice.  Clicking the accept mark is required to Stack Overflow to work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I do not know what a dist is, but with lists this works:

```
>>> 5 not in [1,2,3,4,5]
False
>>> 6 not in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant dict (dictionary) .nyway I got the answer. Thanks