# python KeyError python2.7

Tags: python, keyerror

I have an Python Question and Iam not able to solve it in proper time i think so help would be appreciated.

I have some Data on my Harddrive (JSON) and i managed to parse it.
Unfortually some Keys are missing

Example i want to extracte something based on some keys

```
examples['foo'] = map(lambda example: example['bar']['foo'] if example['bar'] != None else None, examples_data)
```

So Iam aware of that some of the Keys(foo) are missing in my dataset and Iam also aware of that i need to except an Exception KeyError. However I was not able to catch the exception.

Iam using Python 2.7

I have tryed to sourround the block with an try: code catch KeyError: but I think i need to add the try catch block in my loop ?

Iam sorry for such an Noob ProgrammingQuestion but i almost never using python therefore iam a bit rusty.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Please reformat your question in order to make it more readable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you're rusty with Python, you might want to try deconstructing your one-liner into multiple lines using `for x in examples_data` to aid readability

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle undeclared dict key in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755655/handle-undeclared-dict-key-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dict.get](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm):

```
 examples['foo'] = map(lambda example: example.get("bar", {}).get("foo"), examples_data)
```